# How do I properly use char and void prototypes in my code?

Tags: c++

My goal here is have the user pick an operand symbol before the program error checks for correct input and delivers a message as to what type of arithmetic questions will be asked. I don't really understand using char and void prototypes.  This is for an assignment in which i must use and call from these specific functions for these specific actions.

These are the prototypes I need to use:

```
void PrintMenu ();
char GetMenuChoice ();
void TellUserAboutOp (char i);
```

This is what I have in int main():

```
PrintMenu ();
GetMenuChoice();             
TellUserAboutOp (operandChoice);
```

This is what the functions look like so far:

```
void PrintMenu ()
{
   cout << "What operation would you like to practice?" << endl 
   << "Please type the character giving your choice after the small arrow: " 
   << endl << "\t + for addition" << endl << "\t - for subtraction" << endl 
   << "\t * for multiplication" << endl << "\t / for division -> ";

}

char GetMenuChoice ()
{
  char chosenOperand;
  cin >> chosenOperand;

  while ((chosenOperand != '+') || (chosenOperand != '-') || 
  (chosenOperand != '*') || (chosenOperand != '/'));
  {
    cout << "That's not a valid character for your choice. Please try again!" 
    << endl << "Type in the character of your choice -> ";
    cin >> chosenOperand;

  }


return (chosenOperand);

}

void TellUserAboutOp (char i)
{

  if
      (i == '+')
      cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice addition.";

  else if
      (i == '-')
      cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice subtraction.";

  else if
      (i == '*')
      cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice multiplication.";

  else if
      (i == '/')
      cout << "OK, le's try 7 different questions to practice division.";

  return;

}
```

The compile warning is:

```
48): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'operandChoice' used
```

Comment: Did you just "update away" the line that we were correcting our answers? It's doesn't make sense to change the crucial part about a question and thereby invalidate the answers (except if you made a mistake during copy paste). If the answers leave you with another problem, either comment on the answers, add something at the end of your original question or post a new question.

Comment: Now you don't even have a question anymore in your question ("no compile errors or warnings", so why are you asking!?). What is the error?

Comment: Rolled back the changes since they invalidated posted answers.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. So everything works? Why did you change the `while` to an `if` statement? The purpose of the `while` loop was (I guess) to get a character from the user again and again, until it matches one of the operators. An `if` statement will only check once and then continue no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `GetMenuChoice`, it returns a char, which you'll want to store in the operandChoice. A function that returns a non-void type can be used like a variable of that type. So:

```
char operandChoice = GetMenuChoice();
```

will compile and clear out the uninitialized variable warning, while doing what you need. I'm sure your assignment is to understand how function returns values that you can use in assignments and other expressions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the whole code of your `main`, but it seems you have defined a local variable `operandChoice` that you have not given any useful value before you use it. You probably want a line like

```
operandChoice = GetMenuChoice();
```

somewhere in your main. According to its prototype, `GetMenuChoice` *returns* a `char`, meaning that you can assign the result of the function to a `char` variable. You can also initialize `operandChoice` at the location where you declare it by writing

```
char operandChoice = GetMenuChoice();
```

The prototype of the function tells you its signature. The first thing (before the function name) is the return type. `void` is a special return type that indicates the function doesn't actually return anything. So your usage of the other functions is correct. Doing `FunctionName(some arguments)` just executes the function. You *can* do the same thing with a function that returns `char` (or something else), but it will throw away the result returned from the function.

Additional hint: I think you have a problem with your `while` condition in `GetMenuChoice`. The `chosenOperand` variable can only be equal to one of the operand characters. So at least three of your comparisons will always yield true and thus you never exit the `while` loop. You probably want to combine the checks for each operator in a different way than `||` (which means "or").

Also, there is a `;` after your while loop. This will just create an endless `while` loop because the following block enclosed by `{`, `}` will not be considered the body of the loop. Because of the `;`, the while loop has an empty body.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code, accomplishes task.

Changed GetMenuChoice(); in int main() to:

```
char operandChoice = GetMenuChoice();
```

Repaired while loop in function:

```
void PrintMenu ()
{
     cout << "What operation would you like to practice?" << endl 
     << "Please type the character giving your choice after the small arrow: " 
     << endl << "\t + for addition" << endl << "\t - for subtraction" << endl 
     << "\t * for multiplication" << endl << "\t / for division -> ";

}

char GetMenuChoice ()
{
    char chosenOperand;
    cin >> chosenOperand;

    while
        ((chosenOperand != '+') && (chosenOperand != '-') 
        && (chosenOperand != '*') && (chosenOperand != '/'))
    {

    cout << "That's not a valid character for your choice. Please try again!" << endl 
    << "Type in the character of your choice -> ";
    cin >> chosenOperand;

    }

    return (chosenOperand);

}

void TellUserAboutOp (char i)
{

    if
        (i == '+')
        cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice addition." << endl;

    else if
        (i == '-')
        cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice subtraction." << endl;

    else if
        (i == '*')
        cout << "OK, let's try 7 different questions to practice multiplication." << endl;

    else if
        (i == '/')
        cout << "OK, le's try 7 different questions to practice division." << endl;

    return;

}
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you all the time, but from your reputation I see you are new here so I thought a little info on how things work here might help: What you posted is exactly the two things I described in my answer. Why did you post your own answer? Note that while it is usually encouraged to post your own answer on SO, if you figure out the problem yourself, replicating another answer to say, "this worked" is not the way to go. Instead, you accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: I had seen others do it, and I assumed it was the protocol.  I am genuinely trying to do the right thing.  I wanted to be precise in what I was asking for, and hopefully have an easy to read answer for anyone looking in the future.  Thanks for the heads up.  I will not do that again.